# Java Project for vscode doesn't works fine

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, editor

Whenever I create a new maven project in vscode, the **Java Project extension** doesn't update as the file explorer does, so I have to manually clean the workspace caches to make it synchronized. Also, the only file category I could add in **Java Project view** is the .class files, so I have to quire with the explorer. In some cases, suppose I need to add the same file in two or more nested folder like src and target, which is confusing, it' s never the case in eclipse and other refined editors for java, is there a way to solve these two problems?

Comment: Is there an absolute requirement to use VSCode?  I do a lot of tutoring for a local university and the students who use VSCode have so many problems with that Java Extension.  The problems are often very strange to debug, for example \t character needs to be configured in settings if you want TAB to use it instead of "  "(two spaces).

I found this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build
which may or may not highlight what it is you're asking about.

ALSO:

Do you have the entire Java extension pack?  If you do not, try that!

Comment: Not really,but some people recommended vscode for lightweight but strong support for most language, I use eclispe and it's way enough for me,not any bugs but the code completion is much weaker than vscode, I've installed all extension packs for java in vscode,but it seems like bugs and not changing settings could fix.

Comment: @Used To Love For the first question, I recreated a new Maven project, however I don‘t need to empty the workspace. Of course, I've encountered some situations where I need to empty the workspace. And I think it's acceptable to follow the prompts. And can you describe the second question in more detail?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT How do you did that? either do I create a new maven project from Java Project view or from maven view,the new project only display on the file explorer and maven view, it's doesn't appear on Java Project view unless I manually cleaned it, suppose I create a javafx project ,I cannot add an fxml on Java Project view in vscode, I have to add on file explorer, while in eclipse I can achieve this

Comment: @Used To Love

Unless constrained by disc space / processor power / RAM, I don't see too much benefit to the idea of using one 'inferior' IDE for many languages, versus using specialized ones that are designed specifically support the individual language.  "Use the right tool for the right job" rings through my mind in saying this,  A hammer can be used in place of a shovel, but most times... probably shouldn't.

If you want more robust support for AutoComplete / IntelliSense... try IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.  If you enjoy it, the Ultimate version has even more to offer.

Answer (score 1):

I will publish my operation steps in the answer. You can also refer to the official [documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_create-a-new-java-project) for more information on project management

1. Creat java project

[image]

2. Creat a new floder to save Maven

[image]

3. Vscode automatically generates Maven project and workspace environment

[image]

There is no need to empty the workspace. Of course, if you want to create a project in the original directory, it may cause similar problems.

For your second question, I think java project only manages Java classes. If you want to put other file types, why not use file explorer.

Java project has its own things to do

Comment: thank you for answer my question, what I did is open a empty folder and set as 
java workspace, then creating project in this folder, the Extension didn't detect my newly created project and I tried to create from out of this diectory, it worked!, I don't know why this works while my approach doesn't achieve, does this means all my maven projects has to be a distinct folder?

Comment: @Used To Love I reproduced your operation and found no problems. Can you add more detailed operation descriptions and pictures of the problems encountered in the article?

Comment: I did, as you mentioned in your answer, I created a new project in the original directory, for instance, if I set "/users/goodskies" as workspace, than create new projects in "users/goodskies", it won't detected, but if I changed to "/users" it could detect immediately.

Comment: Let me answer your previous question first. There can be two or more Maven items in the same folder. These are the two Maven projects I just created in vscode. They can exist together.https://imgur.com/a/64bQFwj  Of course, after all this, I will use the parent directory as the workspace, because when you create a project, vscode will prompt to ask whether to open this new project. At this time, it will not recognize other projects.

Comment: I tried several times and I seems to got the knack, suppose you create a folder "java/" to store all your projects, then if you set this folder as workspace, the extension won't recognize when you create new project in this folder, but this approach works: open vscode and open a project in "java/"(suppose you hava create one),then create new projects in "java/" it will work, by the time, I notice the workspace name has changed to "untitled".

Comment: @Used To Love Yes, what you said is basically correct.  When you choose "/java" as workspace. You can creat a new project in the floder "/java" itself and vscode can recognize the project as well. Note the inclusion relationship between the workspace and the project.